# Select and scroll to specific row in dojo EnhancedGrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo, row, selection

I have a dojox.EnhancedGrid.

- On load of the grid, I would like to scroll to and select the last row in the grid.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, supposing you have a reference to your grid, called "grid", and that your grid uses pagination :

```
var lastRow = grid.store._arrayOfAllItems.length - 1;
grid.scrollToRow(lastRow);
var lastRowOnPage = grid.rowCount - 1;
grid.selection.addToSelection(lastRowOnPage);
```